# I getting an error, 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I've made a form to store customer feedback, It's working fine. Now my motive is that, create a update feedback form so that a user can be able to update their feedback. I also have made a feedback form, but it's not working perfectly. It shows an error. Please check the `UpdateFeedback` view. Where did the actual problem occur? Please give me the relevant solution...

***views.py:***

*It's working fine made for storing the feedback.*

```
def feedBack(request,quick_view_id):
    quick_view = get_object_or_404(Products, pk=quick_view_id)
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated:

        try:
            ProductREVIEWS.objects.create(
                user=request.user,
                product=quick_view,
                feedBACK=request.POST.get('feedBACK'),
            )
            messages.success(request,"Thanks for your feedback.")
            return redirect('quick_view', quick_view_id)
        except:
            return redirect('quick_view', quick_view_id)

    else:
        return redirect('quick_view', quick_view_id)
```

---

***but the problem is here. It's not working perfectly.***

```
def UpdateFeedback(request, id):
    feedback = ProductREVIEWS.objects.get(pk=id)
    product_id = feedback.product.id
    reviewers = feedback.user
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UpdateFeedback(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and reviewers.id == request.user.id:
            UpdateFeedback(request.POST)
            feedBACK = form.cleaned_data.get('UpdateFeedBACK')
            feedback.feedBACK = feedBACK
            feedback.save()
            messages.success(request, "Comment updated")
    
    return redirect('quick_view', product_id)
```

**forms.py for** `UpdateFeedback`:

```
class UpdateFeedback(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductREVIEWS
        fields = ('feedBACK')
       
        labels = {
            'feedBACK':'Change Your View'
        }

        widgets = {
            'rating':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'style':'font-size:13px;'}),
            'feedBACK':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'style':'font-size:13px;'})
        }
```

***models.py:***

```
class ProductREVIEWS(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='userREVIEW',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name='productREVIEWrelatedNAME',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feedBACK = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

***urls.py:***

```
path("feedBack/<int:quick_view_id>/", views.feedBack, name="feedBack"),
path("UpdateFeedback/<int:id>/", views.UpdateFeedback, name="UpdateFeedback")
```

***template:***

```
{% for feedBack in AllProductFeedback %}
<form action="{% url 'UpdateFeedback' id=feedBack.id %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <textarea id="UpdateFeedBack" rows="6" style="font-size: 13px;" class="form-control" name="UpdateFeedBACK" value="" required>{{feedBack.feedBACK}}</textarea>

</form>
{% endfor %}
```

***error:***

```
AttributeError at /UpdateFeedback/29/
'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/UpdateFeedback/29/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'
Exception Location: D:\1_WebDevelopment\17_Ecomerce Website\ecomerce site\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py, line 22, in _wrapped_view
Python Executable:  D:\1_WebDevelopment\17_Ecomerce Website\ecomerce site\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce site',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python39.zip',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39',
 'D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce site\\env',
 'D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce '
 'site\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 19 Jul 2022 15:54:42 +0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a naming clash between your view and your form - both are called `UpdateFeedback`. So your view is trying to call the view itself - you are passing `request.POST` into the view which thinks it is just `request` - it then tries to call `request.user` but `request` is actually the `request.POST` querydict which does not have user. You should change your form name to `UpdateFeedbackForm` in your `forms.py` and `views.py`.

**Edit** - answering ID issue:

Enter the ID into the form before it's submitted:

```html
{% for feedBack in AllProductFeedback %}
<form action="{% url 'UpdateFeedback' id=feedBack.id %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ feedBack.id }}">
    <textarea id="UpdateFeedBack" rows="6" style="font-size: 13px;" class="form-control" name="UpdateFeedBACK" value="" required>{{feedBack.feedBACK}}</textarea>

</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @OsVoid Yes, it worked.  But now created another problem is, not being stored data in the database.

Comment: After `form.is_valid()` just do `form.save()`

Comment: now it shows,,NOT NULL constraint failed: Ecommerce_app_productreviews.product_id 

Comment: Stick `{{ feedBack.id }}` hidden in your template form somewhere so that it gets passed to the view form

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point......

Comment: Added an update to my answer, hopefully that works for you

Comment: I didn't understand ...Please write the full code that you saying so that I grasp your point.

Comment: Just updated it for you specific code

Comment: where I've to update...I didn't understand sorry

Comment: I've updated your `<form>` element, that's what you need to update